# What is the use of @ and @@ in variables names in TeX/LaTeX?

Tags: macros, package-writing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do LaTeX internal commands have an @ in them?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6240/why-do-latex-internal-commands-have-an-in-them)
>   [What do \makeatletter and \makeatother do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do)
>   [What is the difference between \myname and \my@name while writing a .cls file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11078/2975)

I have tried a few times to write/understand other peoples packages. Though I'm no good yet, I keep running into a definition using `@` or `@@` in the name. Why is this done ? Is there any special meaning ? Is this in any way related to the use of _ and __ in python, where a variable starting with `@` shouldn't really be messed with while one with __ definitely should not be messed with ?

As an example :

`\@author` is used in the class files article.cls but is not defined anywhere. So I assumed the `@` to mean it was some kind of command internal to LaTeX/TeX. While in a custom class file (`res.cls` by Michael DeCorte to be exact) I've seen `\@name` is specifically defined as both

```
\def\name#1{\def\@name{#1}}
```

and

```
\def\@name{}
```

To my knowledge the latter ensures a default value is set up in case the `\name` command is not used by the document writer. But this still doesn't indicate why the `@` is used.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: We had this question before. I'm currently looking for it.

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48207/5049) helps?

Comment: Oh dear, I did search for @ in the search bar and didn't get a response, that's why I posted I didn't realise it was a duplicate, sorry.

Comment: @Carel: No worries. It is pretty much impossible to search for this.