# Need help to understand xkeyval example

Tags: xkeyval

I found an "easy" example how to use xkeyval [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13270/a-package-template-using-xkeyval) using the following code:

```
\ProvidesPackage{myemph}[2011/03/12 v1.0 a test package]

\providecommand\my@emphstyle{\em}

% Note that the argument must be expandable,
% or use xkvltxp package before \documentclass (see manual of xkeyval)
\RequirePackage{xkeyval}
\DeclareOptionX{style}{%
\def\my@emphstyle{\csname my@style@#1\endcsname}}
% predefined styles
\providecommand\my@style@default{\em}
\providecommand\my@style@bold{\bfseries}

\ProcessOptionsX

% For simple key-value commands, keyval would suffie
\define@key{myemph}{code}{%
  \def\my@emphstyle{#1}}
\define@key{myemph}{style}{%
  \def\my@emphstyle{\csname my@style@#1\endcsname}}
\newcommand\setemph[1]{%
  \setkeys{myemph}{#1}}

\renewcommand\emph[1]{%
  {\my@emphstyle #1}}

\endinput
```

Test file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=default]{myemph}

\begin{document}
Something \emph{important}

\setemph{style=bold}
Something \emph{important}

\setemph{code=\Large\sffamily}
Something \emph{important}
\end{document}
```

My first issue is that I dont know what is ment by

```
\providecommand\my@emphstyle{\em}
```

I found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31776/latex-at-symbol) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do) that usually '@' is a letter of category 12 and not 11 and, therefore, can't be used in macros, except you manualy set '@' to category 11, which has not been done in the above code. However, I can compile the latex code. Why does it work?

After ignoring this, I moved on to the line

```
\DeclareOptionX{style}{%
\def\my@emphstyle{\csname my@style@#1\endcsname}}
```

which gave me the pleasure to explore [what \csname does](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39380/what-exactly-do-csname-and-endcsname-do). As far as I understood, it is used to use commands that make use of letters that are not contained in category 11. However, the function '\my@style' has not been definied yet, so I dont see what is happing there. In addition, I do not know what \DeclareOptionX does anyway. I could not find it with google.

After all, I read the offical documentation of the xkeyval package where it was explained how to used it, simply by using the commands '\define@key' and '\setkeys' on page 1. I guess its my bad that I was looking for an easy example to skip the documentation. However, now I am curious how the 'simple' example works.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Firstly `@` is made a letter in package and class files automatically.

```
\DeclareOptionX{style}{%
\def\my@emphstyle{\csname my@style@#1\endcsname}}
```

The xkeyval package uses this to define what happens when in the document you go

```
\setemph{style=bold}
```

basically the (x)keyval parser uses the macro defined by the declaration and passes it the value (the part after `=`) as the TeX argument `#1` so `style=bold` gets executed as

```
 \def\my@emphstyle{\csname my@style@bold\endcsname}
```

which is more or less the same as

```
\def\my@emphstyle{\my@style@bold}
```

but `\csname` has allowed the command name to be constructed at run time.

earlier

```
\providecommand\my@style@bold{\bfseries}
```

had defined `\my@style@bold`  so the end result is that `style=bold` causes `\bfseries` to get executed, and stuff goes bold.

The basic use of keyval is with `\setkeys` but xkeyval also injects the mechanism into the `\usepackage` option handler which by default just accepts a comma separated list of options with no `=` syntax. That is the `\DeclareOptionX` then `\ProcessoptionsX` is the extended version of `\ProcessOptions` that calls `\setkeys` internally so that

```
\usepackage[style=default]{myemph}
```

invokes the key definitions.

Comment: Thank you. Could you also explain why `\setemph{style=bold}` works instead of the described Marco `\setkeys[my]{emphstyle}{style=bold}` as descriped in the offical documentation?

Comment: @Adam oh it's common for packages to do that eg hyperref has `\hypersetup` which similarly is a very thin wrapper around `\setkeys`, it just hides the internal key collection names probably (I haven't looked) `\def\setemph{\setkeys[my]{emphstyle}}`