# TeX Programming questions (and stuff about parcolumns)

Tags: macros, tex-core, programming, parcolumns

I'm trying to modify the inner workings of `parcolumns`. I'm starting to understand the TeX macro "programming" language a bit but I have some issues.

In `paracolumns` there are three issues I want to resolve:

1. Remove vertical space between rows
2. Remove extra column space at end of column
3. Make the above optional.

I've narrowed down, I think the problem to the first to the following code:

```
\vsplit\csname pc@column@\number\count@\endcsname to \dp\strutbox%
\vbox{\unvbox\@tempboxa}%
```

I've tried everything to remove the space that `\vsplit` is suppose to add but I get any different results.

Does

```
\csname pc@column@\number\count@\endcsname to \dp\strutbox%
```

Create a simple macro name by concatenating `pc@column` with the value in number and count?

---

The `parcolumns` code loops over the columns then the rows. It uses a `\repeat` and also recursively calls `\pc@placeboxes`. It has some code to check if the loop is currently at the last column and adds some `\hfill`. I think it does it ad

```
\ifnum\count@<\pc@columncount%
\strut\hfill%
\ifpc@rulebetween\vrule\hfill\fi%
\fi%
```

but commenting all this out doesn't change much if anything. (These are the only lines of code that have `\hfill` them)

---

I see

```
\define@key{parcolumns}{distance}{%
\@tempdimc#1\relax%
}%
```

Creates a keyvalue pair used in the options. I've tried to duplicate this without luck

```
\define@key{parcolumns}{extratopspace}{%
\@tempdimq#1\relax%
}%
```

but I get errors about `\tempdimq` not existing or whatever. The code looks to simply be assigning `\tempdimc` to the first argument and I don't see anywhere where `\tempdimc` is being initalized or created so I figure it is a internal temp variable but then `\tempdimq` should work(unless there are only a,b,c, and d as I've tried e).

---

Any ideas or useful comments? One of the biggest issues I have with the code is there is no indentation. Is it ok to indent code or will the whitespace cause problems?
BTW, I just stumbled on this reference which seems pretty good:

> http://www.tug.org/utilities/plain/cseq.html

Comment: There are quite a number of (La)TeX concepts here: David and I have tried to cover some, but individual ones have come up before as questions.

Answer (score 7):

The format of SE works best of you ask one question per post, but anyway

> Does
>
> ```
> \csname pc@column@\number\count@\endcsname to \dp\strutbox%
> ```
>
> Create a simple macro name by concatenating pc@column with the value
>   in number and count?

yes and no: `\number` is a TeX primitive that returns the decimal expansion of the number stored in the count register so if `\count@` is storing 3 and the depth of strutbox is 5pt then the above expands to

```
\pc@column@3 to 5pt
```

(although you could only enter it that way of 3 had catcode 11: letter)

> but commenting all this out doesn't change much if anything. (These
>   are the only lines of code that have `\hfill` them)

Presumably (without looking at the package) that is padding between the columns so if your column widths are close to filling the available space there will not be much inter-column space to fill anyway.

```
I don't see anywhere where `\tempdimc` is being initalized
```

`\tempdim(a b and c)` are defined within the LaTeX format as scratch registers. If you need more you need to allocate them.

Comment: Why doesn't \count@ automatically expand like any normal macro? and what is the @ for? e.g., if one removed \number what would happen?

Comment: `\count@` is the name of a register, not a macro, so it does not expand. The `@` is part of the name here as it is a 'letter' in this context.

Answer (score 3):

(Taking some of the parts which David has not)

Whitespace at the start of lines will generally be ignored by TeX as after a new line TeX is 'skipping spaces'. So writing for example

```
\define@key{parcolumns}{extratopspace}{%
  \@tempdimc#1\relax
}%
```

is equivalent to writing

```
\define@key{parcolumns}{extratopspace}{%
\@tempdimc#1\relax
}%
```

(It's common to use spaces rather than tabs for indenting in TeX code, as tabs are regarded by many TeX users as something of a pain. Two spaces for indenting are pretty common.) You'll notice that I've remove the `%` after `\relax`: while `%` at the end of lines is commonly used to avoid adding extra spaces into code (as TeX converts line ends to a space), one is not needed after a control word such as `\relax` as TeX is once again skipping spaces here.

David pointed out that `\@tempdimc` is defined by the LaTeX kernel. It's worth noting that this is a TeX register, not a macro, and hence the assignment takes place by putting thee value after the register name. LaTeX provides us with `\setlength` as a wrapper around assigning 'lengths' (which are TeX skip registers), but a lot of LaTeX2e programmers simply use the TeX methods directly.

David has explained that

```
\csname pc@column@\number\count@\endcsname to \dp\strutbox
```

constructs the name `\ps@column@3` if for example `\count@` has value `3`. It's worth noting that again this is not a macro name but a register name, which you can see as it's assigned in the same way as `\@tempdimc` and *not* using `\def` (which would be the case for a macro).

Comment: What is the @ symbol for? I see it used a lot in register names(and macro names too?)

Comment: @Uiy  See for example http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do.

Comment: Also see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6240/why-do-latex-internal-commands-have-an-in-them