# Compare strings

Tags: strings

I have some troubles by comparing strings in my `beamer` theme.

I would like to compare the "techno" argument with a string (iOS, Android, Java,...):

```
if techno =="iOS" logo_path = "some_image" else if techno == "android" logo_path = "some_other_image"
```

and so on,

I take an argument from the main `.tex` files and I would like to compare it do define an image to include :

```
\def\beamer@ALE@iOSLogo{ios.png}
\def\beamer@ALE@AndroidLogo{android_logo.jpeg}

\DeclareOptionBeamer{techno}{\def\beamer@ALE@Techno{#1}}
\ProcessOptionsBeamer

\IfStrEq{\def\beamer@ALE@Techno}{iOS}{{\def\beamer@ALE@TechnoLogo{\beamer@ALE@DiOSLogo}}{{\def\beamer@ALE@TechnoLogo{\beamer@ALE@DefaultLogo}}
```

Then I include a graphics :

```
\includegraphics[width=1cm]{\beamer@ALE@TechnoLogo}
```

When I compile it tolds me : image `ios' (back quote + value + quote) is not found.

I have to declare a macro to solve the problem :

```
\def\beamer@ALE@iOS{iOS}
```

Do someone have some explanations?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem (see some [instructions here](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225)). It will be much easier to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Why is there a `\def` inside `\IfStrEq{\def\beamer@ALE@Techno}{\def\beamer@ALE@iOSLogo}...`? If you want to get the value of `\beamer@ALE@Techno` it should not be there...

Comment: Furthermore, by default you cannot (and should not) use `@` in macros name in the normal text, e.g. see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6240/why-do-latex-internal-commands-have-an-in-them.  Due to a missing MWE it is more difficult to say, but it might be the problem...

Comment: The question has been edited but it still has nowhere near enough information to guess what the question is. Pleas make a [mininimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) as requested in the first comment. (however I'll put another guess in my answer)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is hard to guess from the code fragment which strings you want to compare but
I think you want to compare `\beamer@ALE@Techno` (The option value) with `\beamer@ALE@iOSLogo`
which you can do with

```
\ifx\beamer@ALE@iOSLogo\beamer@ALE@Techno
   ... ios case
\else
  ... other case
\fi
```

---

Your question has

```
\IfStrEq{\def\beamer@ALE@Techno}{iOS}
```

It is hard to guess what the intention of that is as `\IfStrEq`  is intended to compare strings (lists of characters) but you have passed it a definition.

However I don't think you nwant to do a compare at all, just define

```
\def\logoimage{mydefaultimage}
\@namedef{tech-image-ios}{\def\logoimage{ios.png}}
\@namedef{tech-image-android}{\def\logoimage{android_logo}}

\DeclareOptionBeamer{techno}{\csname tech-image-#1\endcsname}}
\ProcessOptionsBeamer

\includegraphics{\logoimage}
```

then it will include an image `mydefaultimage` unlesss techno=ios or techno=android in which case you get teh specified files, more `\@namedef` could be added as required.

Comment: Okay, I edited my first message to give more informations.