# Use and meaning of the symbol at @

Tags: symbols

In many codes I see that there is the symbol `@` appearing (e.g. it often appears in counters). My simple question is: does `@` has a special meaning or it is just a character as others?

Comment: Check out: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6240/why-do-latex-internal-commands-have-an-in-them

Comment: oh, thanks, I searche for a question with @ in the title but I did not found that! that's exactly the answer I was searching for!

Comment: Yeah, searching with special characters is always a bit of an uncertainty. :-) BTW: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)