# New gather and equation environments with a single counter

Tags: equations, numbering, amsmath

So I've created a new equation-style environment with an associated counter to track a certain set of definitions I introduce in my document:

```
\newcounter{defcounter}
\newenvironment{defeq}{%
\refstepcounter{defcounter}
\renewcommand\theequation{D.\thedefcounter}
\begin{equation}}
{\end{equation}}
```

This produces the desired result: a new environment `defeq` just like `equation`, but with its own counter and its own label format (e.g., (D.1)).

But occasionally I'll have several definitions in a row and want to use a `gather` environment to avoid the ugly vertical spacing that results from consecutive `equation` environments. A slight modification of the above *kind of works*:

```
\newenvironment{defgather}{%
\refstepcounter{defcounter}
\renewcommand\theequation{D.\thedefcounter}
\gather}
{\endgather}
```

However, linebreaking with `\\` doesn't seem to step the newly created counter. The following MWE illustrates the issue:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
    \newcounter{defcounter}
    \newenvironment{defeq}{%
    \refstepcounter{defcounter}
    \renewcommand\theequation{D.\thedefcounter}
    \begin{equation}}
    {\end{equation}}

    \newenvironment{defgather}{%
    \refstepcounter{defcounter}
    \renewcommand\theequation{D.\thedefcounter}
    \gather}
    {\endgather}
\begin{document}

\begin{defeq}
    1
\end{defeq}

Text text text text.

\begin{defgather}
    2 \\
    3
\end{defgather}

\end{document}
```

The lines containing "1" and "2" are appropriately labelled -- (D.1) and (D.2). However, the line containing "3" is labelled (D.2) indicating that the `\\` hasn't stepped `defcounter` as the default gather does with the `equation` counter.

How can I fix my new gather environment so that `\\` steps the new counter?

Comment: The `equation` counter is stepped with every `defeq` as well. Is this the expected behaviour? That is, if you put an `equation` before and after everything, you'll have a numbering 1, D.1, D.2, D.2, 5.

Comment: @Werner No, no it isn't. The counters are supposed to be independent. My MWE is even more messed up than I realized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easiest to `\let` the `defcounter` to that of `equation` within your environment(s). That way `defcounter` is stepped whenever `equation` would be:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcounter{defcounter}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{defeq}{%
  \let\c@equation\c@defcounter% equation is equivalent to defcounter
  \renewcommand\theequation{D.\arabic{equation}}
  \begin{equation}}
  {\end{equation}}

\newenvironment{defgather}{%
  \let\c@equation\c@defcounter% equation is equivalent to defcounter
  \renewcommand\theequation{D.\arabic{equation}}
  \gather}
  {\endgather}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  abc \label{eq:first}
\end{equation}

\begin{defeq}
  1 \label{deq:first}
\end{defeq}

There is~\eqref{eq:first}, \eqref{deq:first}, \eqref{deq:second},~\eqref{deq:third} 
and~\eqref{eq:second}.

\begin{defgather}
  2 \label{deq:second} \\
  3 \label{deq:third}
\end{defgather}

\begin{equation}
  abc \label{eq:second}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Would you mind explaining what the `\c@` construct does? I've seen this many times in answers from more experienced users but still seems like black magic to me. The only mention I've seen of it is in [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6240/why-do-latex-internal-commands-have-an-in-them), is that all it's doing here? Is `\c@` how lower leveled commands that reference the counters are named?

Comment: @Dennis: `\newcounter{mycount}` defines a counter register to a macro `\c@mycount`. And to access `@` symbols you need a [`\makeatletter`...`\makeatother` pair](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351/5764). All I did was to sync the counter register of `equation` with that of `defcounter` (through `\let\c@equation\c@defcounter`). This way, when TeX steps `equation` (and therefore the counter `\c@equation`, it actually steps `\c@defcounter`, leaving the original `\c@equation` untouched.

Comment: @Dennis: So, we make TeX think that "Dave" is now "Dan". Every call to "Dave" is actually "Dan"... only temporarily, since the switch is grouped and therefore have limited scope. The true "Dave"-"Dan" relation is reestablished after the environment closes.