# Is it possible to use the singulars for the items in "Personal information" in europecv

Tags: europecv

I am using europecv and defined my personal information using its commands (like this):

```
\ecvname{Hüsken, Nathan}
```

Now, when I put in

```
\ecvpersonalinfo
```

The output uses:

```
Surname(s) / First name(s)
```

As the item title. Can I somehow make it singular (remove the s)?
I want to do the same for all the other items in "Personal information".

Of course, I could just not use the "\ecvpersonalinfo" command, but I am  trying to stick to it.

Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,nologo,notitle,noflag,booktabs]{europecv}
\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}

\ecvname{Hüsken, Nathan}

\begin{document}

\begin{europecv}
\ecvpersonalinfo

\end{europecv}

\end{document}
```

which prouces this output:

[image]

Comment: Could you please include a complete MWE?

Comment: @LaRiFaRi edited to add the MWE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class `europecv` simulates the form of the official Europe CV for the EU (old version before 2013. the current version can be used with class `europecv2013`). See more information on the [homepage of europass in english](https://europass.cedefop.europa.eu/en/documents/curriculum-vitae/templates-instructions).

Please see that there are two versions of the europass, an older one (class `euroecv`, today outdated, you used it in your screenshot) and the current one (class `europecv2013`, see examples on homepage in given link).

As you can see both versions are official documents used in europe. The class `europecv` simulates this old official document so changes on the template should **not be done**, if you want to use the resulting CV in Europe.

Answer (score 3):

Although I think the accepted answer provides a good answer, I also had the same issue. I wanted to change the output of a predefined command because in Germany we normally write E-Mail and not E-mail with a lowercase “m”, which is predefined.
For your case you just have to write

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\ecv@namekey}{Surname / First name}
\makeatother
```

after your usepackages.

More info about `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` can be found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6240/why-do-latex-internal-commands-have-an-in-them)