# how to prevent \input from failing if the file is missing?

Tags: input

I read here (second comment to the question)

[When should I use \input vs. \include?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-input-vs-include)

that `\@input` "does not throw an error if the file does not exist".

If I try

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\@input{toBeIncluded.tex}
\end{document}
```

I indeed get no *fatal* error, but still i get 3 compilation errors and, more importanly, my pdf contains the word "inputtoBeIncluded.tex".

Is there a simple way to *completely ignore* the input command if the input file does not exist?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! Because of the special character `@` in the command name you need to write `\makeatletter\@input{...}\makeatother`.

Comment: @AndrewSwann --- quicker by 6 seconds. If you make your comment into an answer, I will delete mine.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6240/15925

Comment: `\InputIfFileExists{file}{then}{else}`, you can just leave then, else blank. For details see `texdco source2e`

Comment: @daleif Please, add an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `\makeatletter` to enable the use of the symbol `@` in a macro.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
abc
\makeatletter
\@input{myfile.tex}
\makeatother   

\end{document}
```

**EDIT**

As noted by @Emil Jeřábek, this has the side effect of changing the catcode of @ whilst `myfile.tex` is being read. This is unlikely to have any adverse effects, but it could be avoided as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\let\conditionalinput\@input
\makeatother

\begin{document}
abc
\conditionalinput{fred.tex}
\end{document}
```

That said, it's probably better to use `\InputIfFileExists{file}{}{}`, as suggested by @daleif.

Comment: Isn't it easier to just use `\InputIfFileExists{file}{}{}`?

Comment: @daleif --- probably, but I didn't know that one.

Comment: thanks a lot to everybody!!! \makeatletter ... seems to do the job but i ll also explore the other option.. thanks again

Comment: This has the side effect that @ is treated as a letter during the tokenization of the content of myfile.tex. This might or might not be desirable.

Comment: I undedrstand that there might be an issue if your included doc has a @? Right? Dont understand details though? Could you pls give me an example?

Comment: @Giulioo --- It's unlikely to have any adverse effects, because most `.tex` files don't use this symbol (it is common in classes and packages). I have edited my question to show how the issue can be avoided, but you can almost get away with ignoring it.

Comment: @Giulioo --- No problem. Note that 'almost' should read 'almost certainly' in my last comment.

Answer (score 21):

Instead of using `\@input` the better method is probably to use

```
\InputIfFileExists{file}{then}{else}
```

This will run `\input` on `file` if it exists, and then execute the code in `then`. If the file does not exist, the code  in `else` is executed. You could for example add a warning in the `else` part, just to inform you that this particular file was not found.

If you just want a blink input if the file exists, just use

```
\InputIfFileExists{file}{}{}
```

For more details on this macro see `texdoc source2e` it is described in the `ltfiles.dtx` part, secion 19, **File handling**

Comment: the behavior of InputIfFileExists looks very very odd to me. To begin with if i try \documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\InputIfFileExists{iDontExist.tex}{}{}
\end{document} i simply get an error! Also it seems to "remember" things from the previously compiled pdf file.. What am i missing?

Comment: @Giulioo  Exactly which error do you get? Your example compiles fine for me (pdflatex), thoug you get a warning (not an error) that there is no output.

Comment: thx. I was compiling through texnich center.. but even if i do through pdflatex i still get no pdf. But i think the issue is that he does not like a completely empty pdf as output. Indeed even this does not work for me:\documentclass{article} \begin{document} \end{document} (I dont undertsand why: looks like a bug to me). As soon as i have some text it seems to work. Let me play a bit more with it and will see.

Comment: @Giulioo exactly which LaTeX version do you have? If the only contents of your file is the attempt to input a non-existing file, then of course there is no output. If your LaTeX installation is too old that may lead to an error

Comment: pdflatex --version returns MiKTeX-pdfTeX  (MiKTeX 2.9.6300 64-bit). Dont you agree that the output of \documentclass{article} \begin{document} \end{document} should be an empty pdf rather than no pdf at all?

Comment: @Giulioo no, if there is no output to the PDF, there is no reason to make an empty pdf.

Comment: ok thx a lot for your help. All the confusion came from the fact that my example was too simplified.. I m now using InputIfFileExists and will see how it goes

Comment: What to write in the `{else}` to make the compilation stop with error of missing file?

Comment: @Diaa I usually use `\ERROR` or use the packageerror commands

Comment: @daleif I asked the question here https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/576137/2288 in case you are interested in giving another answer, Thanks