# Modify command definition with @ sign

Tags: macros, environments, journal

I was taking a look at the post [Why do LaTeX internal commands have an @ in them?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6240/why-do-latex-internal-commands-have-an-in-them) and one of the answers says:

> Others have mentioned the protection against user definition / redefinition.

And I want to know if that is true, with a source if possible. Is it possible to modify a command that starts with the "at" sign?

More specifically, I am using the [`jmlr2e.sty`](http://www.jmlr.org/format/jmlr2e.sty) file. I want to modify the `\bf Editor` on the line that starts with `\def\@starteditor`, but I want to modify it on the `.tex` file, instead of modifying it in the `jmlr2e.sty` file.

```
\def\maketitle{\par
 \begingroup
   \def\thefootnote{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
   \def\@makefnmark{\hbox to 0pt{$^{\@thefnmark}$\hss}}
   \@maketitle \@thanks
 \endgroup
\setcounter{footnote}{0}
 \let\maketitle\relax \let\@maketitle\relax
 \gdef\@thanks{}\gdef\@author{}\gdef\@title{}\let\thanks\relax}

\def\@startauthor{\noindent \normalsize\bf}
\def\@endauthor{}
\def\@starteditor{\noindent \small {\bf Editor:~}}
\def\@endeditor{\normalsize}
\def\@maketitle{\vbox{\hsize\textwidth
 \linewidth\hsize \vskip \beforetitskip
 {\begin{center} \Large\bf \@title \par \end{center}} \vskip \aftertitskip
 {\def\and{\unskip\enspace{\rm and}\enspace}%
  \def\addr{\small\it}%
  \def\email{\hfill\small\sc}%
  \def\name{\normalsize\bf}%
  \def\AND{\@endauthor\rm\hss \vskip \interauthorskip \@startauthor}
  \@startauthor \@author \@endauthor}

  \vskip \aftermaketitskip
  \noindent \@starteditor \@editor \@endeditor
  \vskip \aftermaketitskip
}}

\def\editor#1{\gdef\@editor{#1}}
```

Comment: Either copy the code from the `.sty` package and change it in your `.tex` file or apply a patch with `etoolbox` or `xpatch` packages; regardless what you do however, you need a `\makeatletter...\makeatother` pair embracing your code changes

Comment: I tried using `etoolbox` but it didn't do the job, so I thought it was because the commands that start with `@` are not patchable. If that's not true, I think I can try it again and see If I did somthing wrong; but I'm still curious about the redefinition question

Comment: I tried to copy the code and to use toolbox, but in one of those cases I got `Missing \begin{document}` even though that line was already there on the tex file

Comment: But you did use `\makeatletter...\makeatother`, right?

Comment: @TeXnician Actually no, I didn't. What is that for?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do

Comment: It's a safety mechanism so that users do not change commands that are used in packages ;) But this enables you to use @ as a letter within commands (letter cat code).

Comment: Sweet! The responses were pretty fast, thank you all of you! Now, should I delete this question? Now that I look at it, it seems like a duplicate

Comment: You should not delete it, but it's probably a duplicate (even of the linked question, because the answer already contains the `\makeatletter` approach).

Comment: Did you know that the `jmlr2e.sty` package has been replaced by the [`jmlr`](https://ctan.org/pkg/jmlr) class? If you're planning on submitting an article with it, it will have to be changed to the new class before publication.

Comment: @evaristegd: I clearly wrote  that you need a `\makeatletter ... \makeatother` pair -- no wonder ,it failed ....

Comment: @ChristianHupfer yeah, sorry I missed that