# Defining running headers

Tags: header-footer

I'm formatting a paper for a journal that uses the style sheet `rmj-public.cls`.  The formatted output includes a running title at the top of each page. The default text used for the running title is the title defined using the `\title{}` command.  Unfortunately, the title is too long to fit, so I'd like to define a short title.  `rmj-public.cls` seems to contain code for using a short title, but I don't know what code I have to use to define it.
The entire style sheet is available at https://rmmc.asu.edu/rmj/RMJstyle.html
The lines of the style sheet that I think are important are

```
\def\@prepheadcontent{%
  \uppercasenonmath\shorttitle
  \ifx\@empty\shortauthors \let\shortauthors\shorttitle
  \else \andify\shortauthors \uppercasenonmath\shortauthors\fi 
  }
```

In this code, I don't understand the meaning of the `@` sign, e.g.
`@prepheadcontent` and `@empty`.
I also don't understand how to define `shorttitle` and `shortauthors`.

Comment: About `@` see [Why do LaTeX internal commands have an @ in them?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6240/123129).

Answer (score 1):

The `rmj-public` class is based on `amsart`, which in turn defines the title with an optional argument to use for headers:

```
\title[<short title>]{<complete title>}
```

[image: a]

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass{rmj-public}    

\usepackage{kantlipsum}% ONLY dummy text

%{ package and environment declarations }


\title[A short title for headings]{An article with a title to long to fit An article with a title to long to fit  An article with a title to long to fit  An article with a title to long to fit}

\author{First Author}
\address{First Author Address, Country}
\email{firstauthor email Address}
\thanks{My thanks}

\author{Second Author}
\address{Second Author Address, Country}
\email{secondauthor email Address}
\thanks{More thanks }

\date{month,day,year}

\keywords{keyword}
\subjclass{general}

\begin{document}
    \begin{abstract}
    \kant[1]
    \end{abstract}
    \maketitle
    
    \section{Introduction}
    
    \kant[1-5]

\end{document}
```

Comment: That solved the problem. Thanks.